# saving prediction from pyspark into HDFS is very slow on yarn (cluster or client)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

```
df = rf_model.transform(df).select("id", "probability", "prediction")

df = df.withColumn("prediction", df["prediction"].cast(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("probability", df["probability"].cast(StringType()))

df.show()

save_path = "hdfs://.../......"
df.write.parquet(path=save_path, mode="overwrite")
```

df.write... is very slow about 8h.

df.show() is very fast about 2min.

The input data is 3GB and the format is parquet.

The output data is less than 1GB.

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-executors 20 \
--driver-memory 6G \
--executor-memory 3G \
```

spark version: 2.4.3

Comment: Hi show() takes only 20 record and stop execution . you can say it stop exaction as soon it get 20 record.

Comment: @sandeeprawat, Thanks! I got it, but the input data is only 3GB and output is less than 1GB, and why is df.write so slow?

Comment: for writing parquet it require all data in ram to make column format  may be there app is not getting enough memory it will be doing swap in swap out..

Comment: The requested memory of my spark-submit far exceeds the data size,  the memory should be enough.   spark tasks: 200,   the data size is much smaller than the memory of executor.

Comment: The raw data is stored on SSD. The execution time of each task in the data writing phase is very long.